# How to define a class inherited from the Zero class that allows you to modify the self._x variable

Tags: python, class, inheritance, self

This is my Zero class:

```py
class ZeroClass():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x
    def __call__(self, w):
        return w * self._x
```

If I run the code below, it returns 500:

```py
s = ZeroClass(100.)
print(s(5))
```

Now, I need to implement the class 'AdjustZero' allowing to change the variable `self._x` through `xSet` method

```
class AdjustZero(ZeroClass):
    def xSet():
```

How can this be done?

Comment: What have you tried, and what problem(s) did you have?

Comment: I don't know what I have to do

Comment: Set `self._x` it just like you've done it in the `Scale`'s `__init__` method: `def xSet(self, new_x): self._x = new_x`.

Comment: What is `xSet` supposed to *do* to `self.x`?

Comment: @ScottHunter it will change its value

Comment: @jfaccioni If I call ```ap.wset(10)``` it throws ```TypeError: wset() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given```

Comment: "This is my Zero class" is not followed by a definition of a Zero class.  And in order to implement `xSet`, you'll need to know what to change `self.x` *to*.

Comment: @Zico sorry I forgot to add `self` to the call. Edited it now.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote wrong the class name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to assign the variable like that. I assumed that your `Zero` class is just your `Scale` class.

```
class Scale:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x

    def __call__(self, w):
        return w * self._x


class AdjustZero(Scale):
    def xSet(self, x):
        self._x = x


s = AdjustZero(100.)
print(s(5))
s.xSet(10)
print(s(5))
```

The output is :

```
500.0
50
```

Comment: I wrote wrong the class name, I updated now, but your answer works, thank you

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

First, the name of Scale should be "Zero" if you intend it to be the Zero class, like so: `class Zero:`. Scale can be renamed to Zero to do this. Class definitions that don't inherit from other classes also don't need parentheses*.

Next, methods of a class should all have a parameter "self" in them, like so: `def xSet(self)`. xSet(self) also needs the new value you're setting to, so the needs to be a parameter as well: `xSet(self, new_x)`. Lastly, the method needs to adjust self._x and change it to new_x, so:

```py
class AdjustZero(Zero):
    def xSet(self, new_x):
        self._x = new_x
```

Also of note: if you want all scales that are subclasses of Zero to have adjustable zeroes, you can move the xSet method into the Zero class.

It also might make sense to keep the name "Scale" and make AdjustZero inherit from Scale for clarity.

*Classes in Python 3 implicitly inherit from "object", whereas in Python 2, this had to be explicitly indicated by defining classes as `class class_name(object):` If this is intended for Python 2 in any way, all classes you write should explicitly inherit from object.